# Reading from CSV who has char and int

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I got a task. The input of the Java Decathlon program is a CSV-like text file. The task is to output an XML file with all athletes in ascending order of their places, containing all the input data plus total score and the place in the competition (in case of equal scores, athletes must share the places, e.g. 3-4 and 3-4 instead of 3 and 4)

This is my cvs file:

```
Jana Kari;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72 
Eva Narun;13.04;4.53;7.79;1.55;64.72;18.74;24.20;2.40;28.20;6.50.76 
Maja Hope;13.75;4.84;10.12;1.50;68.44;19.18;30.85;2.80;33.88;6.22.75 
Kirke Kanda;13.43;4.35;8.64;1.50;66.06;19.05;24.89;2.20;33.48;6.51.01
```

I got these constants for each decathlon event

```
double[] A = new double[]{25.4347,0.14354,51.39,0.8465,1.53775,5.74352,12.91,0.2797,10.14,0.03768};
double[] B = new double[]{18,220,1.5,75,82,28.5,4,100,7,480};
double[] C = new double[]{1.81,1.4,1.05,1.42,1.81,1.92,1.1,1.35,1.08,1.85};
```

Formula for points is

```
Points = INT(A(B — P)^C) for track events (faster time produces a better score)
Points = INT(A(P — B)^C) for field events (greater distance or height produces a better score)
```

"P" is persons records (from cvs). I dont really understand how to read properly from file that it would allow me to do calculations with numbers only. Should i use two dimensional array for cvs file ? Its very confusing and im stuck.

**EDIT**

Well i believe for outputing later to xml file one dimensional array is better. The point of my task is code simplicity, but CVS file may be expanded to N lines so i never know how much rows it will have. I want to use number array in this code:

```
 double[] A = new double[]{25.4347,0.14354,51.39,0.8465,1.53775,5.74352,12.91,0.2797,10.14,0.03768};
 double[] B = new double[]{18,220,1.5,75,82,28.5,4,100,7,480};
 double[] C = new double[]{1.81,1.4,1.05,1.42,1.81,1.92,1.1,1.35,1.08,1.85};
 double PTS;
 double finalscore;

    for (int i = 0; i < P.length;i++ )
    {
    finalscore=0;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            PTS = A[i]* Math.pow((P[i]-B[i]),C[i]);
        }
           else if   (i == 4)
            {
            PTS = A[i]* Math.pow((P[i]-B[i]),C[i]);
            }
            else if (i == 5 || i == 9)
            {
            PTS = A[i]* Math.pow((P[i]-B[i]),C[i]);
            }
        else
        {
        PTS = A[i]* Math.pow((P[i]-B[i]),C[i]);
        }

        finalscore = finalscore + PTS;
    }
  System.out.println(finalscore);
}
```

}

Where P[] would be array first lane of number without name.
P.S it seems code above gives me result NaN when i use

```
 double[] P = new double[]{12.61,5.00,9.22,1.50,60.39,16.43,21.60,2.60,35.81,5.272};
```

Comment: I noticed a problem. The last "number" on each row of the CSV file is not a single number - it has two periods, not one, so they can't be decimal points. What is it, and what does it mean?

Comment: Is it a time - minutes, then seconds, then hundredths of a second? As it is athletics, I guess it is. Can you confirm please?

Comment: Yes its minutes and seconds and hundredths of seconds. I edited my example just to see if it works. I will later change P[] last number to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the right idea - you can use a two dimensional array. I would also recommend you create a class called `Person`, as this is Java programming and Java is object-oriented, but if you have not studied creating multiple classes yet, you can skip that bit and just do it with two arrays, one one-dimensional array for the names and one two-dimensional array for the numbers.

For the one-dimensional array approach

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   double[] scores;
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
   int hundredths;

   public Person(String line) {
      String[] splitted = line.split(";");
      name = splitted[0];
      // now fill in the other fields
      for(int i = 1; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
         scores[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble(splitted[i]);
      }
      String times = splitted[splitted.length - 1].split("\\.");
      minutes = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
      // etc. - fill in the rest
   }
}
```

(Actually, this might be wrong, because I assumed most of the numbers are scores, but I guess they are really seconds and hundredths of a second. It doesn't really matter, unless you could have a time over one minute for those events.)

Then you need to have an array of Person objects in your other class - let's make it quite big so that it will be big enough hopefully:

```
Person[] array = new Person[10000];
```

Now have a loop, and whenever you read a `line` from the file you just call the constructor.

```
array[j] = new Person(line);
```

Nice approach, isn't it?

Comment: Well i do not clearly understand what your code does. In that CVS not every number is time : first, fifht, sixth and last number are in time (seconds and hundreths or minutes, seconds and hundreths) other ones are in meters. I can do the calculation and puting into XML document by my self but i dont understand how to read from that txt file. I can put file contents into 2 dimensional array but it will put Name as first item and it will not let me calculate further. I hope it gave you more information about my problem, if not ask my something specific if you have in mind

Comment: Well you asked for the object-oriented solution, but clearly you do not understand object-orientation. Or what...? It's extremely annoying when you say "I don't understand your code" but you don't say what you don't understand.

Comment: Ah i understand your coded now you take name from CVS and put it in splitted[0] and scores to scores[i-1] (because total line lenght is 10]. I dont need to split time into minutes seconds and hundreths because constants (from A[] B[] C[]) are all in seconds.hundreths or meters.centimeters. I just need to understand reading part from file. You showed me a good aproach how to store into array but i need how to read correctely from file so i could store. I pray i made it more clearly for you. Thank you for your fast replays i really aprieciate it

Comment: So to read from the file you need to use: `BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.csv"));` Then you can say `String line = buf.readLine()` to read a line. This is standard Java code that you can find from Googling.